# Showing newest data with Entity Framework on WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I'm using WPF with Entity Framework and SQL, but i have a problem. Start, i'm created new data with status = false on desktop app. Next, i'm updated data on another device ( change status "false" => "true" ), and now i'm comeback to desktop app and query data with condition status = "true", load the data and binding on listview success, but on the column status data, it showing "false",it is show the right data is "true" when im restart the app. So, how can i show the newest data on Views immediately

I don't know how can it load the data with condition "true" but showing data is "false"

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            ListInventory = new ObservableCollection<Models.Inventory>(DataProvider.Ins.DB.Inventory
                .Where(x => x.StatusInventory == true)
                .Include(x => x.InventoryDetail));
        }
```

Sorry for my bad english.

UPDATE:
I'm reload Dbcontext and it worked properly but i don't think it's the solution

```
var entity = DataProvider.Ins.DB.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToArray();
        foreach (var item in entity)
        {
            item.Reload();
        }
```

Comment: When you assign a new value to the ListInventory property, its setter must fire a change notification, i.e. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: yes, thank you for the suggestion, i tried it, but not working. a note that i updated the data with mobile app not desktop app, when i go back to desktop app i loaded it into another listview and it still shows displayed as "false"